# Remove lines based on missing information using sed

Tags: unix, sed, design-patterns, data-management

I have a data set that is sectioned very specifically, but rather inconveniently, like this:

```
data <- textConnection("rs1050,15,234323,C,T
1,7329,0.1147,-0.0024,0.0048
1,9810,0.6399,0.001174,0.006095
1,16550,0.648541108,0.0061,0.0070
rs7895,NA,NA,A,C
1,997,NA,NA,0.0732
1,9810,0.0339,-0.016131,0.021611
1,16550,0.32739678,0.0014,0.0053
rs995,18,100336,C,T
1,7385,0.2692,-0.0063,0.0035
1,9810,0.5397,-0.002697,0.006012
1,16550,0.651147483,-0.0045,0.0053")
test_data <- read.csv(data, header = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

If the lines containing `rs####` include `NA` (in one or multiple columns), they need to be removed. This would be no problem to do in and of itself, but in this case, the three lines below this row also need to be removed (regardless of if all the data is present in those lines).

So, in the case of the above data, lines 5-8 would all be removed.

Any solution would be great, but my efforts thus far have been based on sed. Something like this?

```
sed -i '/rs*\t*\tNA\tNA\t*/~1-3d' test_data

sed -i '/rs*\t*\tNA\tNA\t*/,+3d' test_data
```

I feel like I'm close, any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to delete the last *after* the first rs7895, too (the one with the two NA's)? And the second rs line (rs995) ?

Comment: I want to delete the line containing rs7895, and the three lines after it (4 lines total). In other words, I want to delete all lines associated with and including the line containing rs7895.

Comment: Exactly three: `sed '/^rs7895,NA,NA,/,+3d'` ? All rsxxx,NA lines plus the three following lines: `sed '/^rs[0-9]+,NA,NA,/,+3d'` BTW: \t is TAB, I see no tabs in the above fragment.

Comment: My actual data is tab delimitated, I just used csv to share a small sample - should have made that clear, sorry! This line isn't working for me, unfortunately. It just prints out the same output.

Comment: Ok, then just replace the commas in my fragment with \t again : `sed '/^rs[0-9]+\tNA\tNA\t/,+3d' should work. Also note that in *true* regexps, '*' does not stand for "any stretch of characters", but for "the previous pattern can repeat zero or more times".

Comment: I did not know that about "*" - thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fine, unless your actual data has training `")`...

```
sed  '/^rs.*NA/,+3d' test_data
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I need it to.

Comment: The original poster doesn't say what platform she's on, but note that this answer requires GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^rs[0-9]+\tNA\tNA\t/,+3d' <input_data >output_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory alternative using `awk`:

```
awk '/^rs.*NA/ { output = 0; } /^rs/ && !/NA/ { output = 1; } output { print }'
```

Could probably be a little better optimized, but there's the proverbial exercise for the reader...

This has three parts - if a line starts with `rs` and contains `NA`, it turns off the `output` variable. If a line starts with `rs` and doesn't contain `NA`, it turns `output` back on. Then, if `output` is currently on, it prints the line, regardless of whether it contains `rs` or `NA`.

Comment: What does this do with the lines that look like this: `1,997,NA,NA,0.0732` ?

Comment: @RobDavis Prints them if `output == 1`. The original question, at least to my reading, only cared about `NA` if the line started with `rs`, but I may be reading that wrong... Added a little more clarification to the answer.

Comment: Oh wait, I see. Right. Carry on. :-)